# How to use session.flush() within the transaction in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am migrating hibernate from 3.X to hibernate version 5.4.2. I am getting the below error while doing flush operation

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3619)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1474)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1470)
```

After setting the value `hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true`it is working fine.
I do not want to use `hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true.` property as it is against atomicity concept. Is there any way to run the flush within transaction.

Comment: Please show us your code. Exception says that no transaction is in progress, so you would need start transaction.

Comment: It is difficult to share my current application code. Let me try to simulate the issue using test application and will share it. It might help me to get the answer too.

Comment: @Technogix, please let me know if you have found the answer to this. Have you implemented this without hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true property.

Comment: Having similar issue and concern. Let me know if you have solved this issue?

Comment: @RimjhimDoshi I did not find any other way in hibernate 5 other than setting the hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true property. I am using it and do not see any problem.  I found this, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.html#ALLOW_UPDATE_OUTSIDE_TRANSACTION
Let me know if you found anything else.

Answer (score 0):

No, no way.

If you does not set `hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true`, by default it will be `false` and deny any update operations outside of a transaction boundary. This can be seen even by the name of the exception.

But why `hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true` property is against atomicity concept? On the contrary, the concept of atomicity assumes that the set of operations will be performed atomically, i.e. either completely successfully or completely fails. Transactions just provide this atomicity.

Comment: If transactions provides atomicity as you say, then **allowing updates outside transactions** breaks this atomicity and thus is against atomicity concept.